# .NET SDK version 5.0 is successfully installed but dotnet --list-sdks show only 3.1.415 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/148/sdk]

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ubuntu, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I want to install multiple version of .NET core on Ubuntu 20.4

In my PC, `3.1.415 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/148/sdk]` is already installed.
Now I want to install version 5.0

I follow this article https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/.NET,

Here is the screenshot of my Terminal
[image: My Terminal]

See, The terminal shows `dotnet-install: Installation finished successfully.` 
But In the outcome of `dotnet --list-sdks`  command only shows
`3.1.415 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/148/sdk]`

What is issue?
How can I install multiple version of .NET SDK in ubuntu 20.4

Comment: Did `/home/thanu/.dotnet` get added to your current PATH? In your screenshot it says the change will only be visible when sourcing the script.

Answer (score 2):

You try to download the tar.gz package from

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet

and then stop explaining on this page:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/dotnet && tar zxf dotnet-sdk-6.0.100-preview.3.21202.5-linux-x64.tar.gz -C $HOME/dotnet
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet
```

After that, you can test the installation by running：

```
> dotnet --list-sdks 
5.0.203 [/home/me/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.100-preview.3.21202.5 [/home/me/dotnet/sdk]
```

Also refer to this article:

https://superuser.com/questions/1440740/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-net-sdk-on-ubuntu